# Add a custom permission to a User

Tags: django, django-permissions

I'd like to be able to give some existing Users a custom permission which I will require for accessing a view.

I think I need to add the new permission to the Postgres table `auth_permission`, but I suspect there is a higher-level way to do this.  Also there is a column in `auth_permission` for `content_type` and I don't know what its value should be.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Have a look at how to [create custom permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) in the docs.

```
class USCitizen(models.Model):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("can_drive", "Can drive"),
            ("can_vote", "Can vote in elections"),
            ("can_drink", "Can drink alcohol"),
        )
```

Then run `python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate`.

Use the [permission_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) to restrict access to your view.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. What initially confused me was that it creates a new model just for the permission. But I guess that makes sense.

Comment: this didn't work for me. I changed the tuple to a list and it worked. The permissions looked like.
permissions = [ ("",""),("","")]

Comment: How do you dynamically make this in the VUE UI?

Comment: Ritesh above is correct, as also confirmed by the docs, at least for current Django version 3.2 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions