# Creating and setting permissions in Django

Tags: django

Let's say I have an app called Blog which contains Posts. I want a user to be able to add and change posts, but not delete them.

The Django docs have this example

```
from myapp.models import BlogPost
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(BlogPost)
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_publish',
                                       name='Can Publish Posts',
                                       content_type=content_type)
```

I don't see how it's actually defining anything here, it just gives it a name and content type.

Django also has basic permission checking

> Assuming you have an application with an app_label foo and a model named Bar, to test for basic permissions you should use:

```
add: user.has_perm('foo.add_bar')
change: user.has_perm('foo.change_bar')
delete: user.has_perm('foo.delete_bar')
```

In my app they would become:

```
add: user.has_perm('blog.add_post')
change: user.has_perm('blog.change_post')
delete: user.has_perm('blog.delete_post')
```

How do I create and add such permissions to a user (in code, not the admin)?

Comment: Why not create a Group with add and change permissions, but not delete.  For every user that registers, it is assigned to that group.

Comment: I would but I still need to know how to create (or add them to the group, since it looks like they already exist) these permissions.

Comment: This is a little old but may help you: http://web.archive.org/web/20130205133031/http://parand.com/say/index.php/2010/02/19/django-using-the-permission-system/

Answer (score 0):

Defining custom permissions in code can be done via a model's meta (see [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1876447/3208419)):

```python
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (('can_publish', 'Can Publish Posts'),)
```

Per user permissions should not be added in code for the most part, but may however be added as part of a migration if using south or the built-in django migrations if your version is high enough.

```bash
python manage.py schemamigration $appname $migration_description --empty
```

```python
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        daemon = orm.User.objects.get(username='daemon')
        daemon.user_permissions.add($permission)
        daemon.save()

    def backwards(self, orm):
        daemon = orm.User.objects.get(username='daemon')
        daemon.user_permissions.remove($permission)
        daemon.save()
```