# Django user permission inside template

Tags: django, django-permissions

I created a custom auth permission in django via admin site, and i added that permission to a user (not a group), now i want to ask if the request user in a template has it but nothing works.It's not a duplicate, i already checked similar questions and none of this work:

```
{% if perms.auth.add_something %}

{% if 'auth.add_something' in request.user.get_all_permissions %}

{% if request.user.has_perm('add_something') %}
```

I add my view:

```
class NotificationSelectView(View):

    template = 'myapp/notification_read.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        t = tree(request)
        req_var_list = []
        analist = notifications_list(request.user)
        level = LevelProcess.objects.get(
            level_hierarchical = 3
        )
        subprocess= Process.objects.filter(level = level)
        user = request.user
        t.update({
           'subprocess': subprocess,
           'analist':analist,
        })
        return render(request, self.template, t)
```

The idea it's to make it inside template, not to use more code in views.
Any ideas ?, thanks in advance.

Comment: show your view. Particularly where does this perms come from?

Comment: I created a permission via admin site, it belongs to auth, but i don't know why it doesn't work, my view doesn't mention perms at all its just assigned to a specific user via admin site too.

Comment: @e4c5 awright i just added it

Comment: @jsanchezs make sure you have this context processor in your settings: `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

django in template it uses the variable perms for the permissions of the logged in user so you can use inside template

```
{% if perms.auth.add_something %}
 {{do_smth}}
{% endif %}
```

from the django documentation there is a section [Authentication data in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates) which describes also permissions in templates

Comment: thanks for your answer, tried that too and doesn't work either...do i have to send something from the view in order to do this ?

Comment: in order to use custom perms you can read also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1876447/924300